# How to resolve ASP.Net "Input string was not in a correct format" error when using session variable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to get the ID of a user from an ASP.NET Session variable which has been set upon the log on of the user. So far I have tried:

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="useridsource" runat="server">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="myuser" SessionField="user" Type="string" />
  </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code to get the ID of the user from the session variable:

```
int userid = Convert.ToInt16("SELECT  [ID] * FROM [users] WHERE ([email] = @myuser)");
```

query to then insert the user ID into a Post table:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO userpost(categoryID, userID, adtitle, addescription, adphoto, uploadeddate) VALUES(@categorydata, @userid, @adtitle, @description, @image, @date)";
```

I know there is an issue with setting int userid in my code, but for the life of me I can not work out how to fix it.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that the string `SELECT ...` can be parsed as a number? It sounds like you actually want to run the query.

Comment: your use of `Convert.ToInt16(...)` doesn't make sense, usually it would look something like this: `Convert.ToInt16("15")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First connect to the database, execute your SQL command, then convert the returned ID to an integer.

```
int userid;
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] FROM [users] WHERE ([email] = @myuser)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        userid =  Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")));
    }
}

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks suggets, your problem is that you try to convert the string `"SELECT  [ID] * FROM [users] WHERE ([email] = @myuser)"` to an integer, which it obviously can't.

I think you meant to first query your SQL database using the string you tried to convert, and then when you have the resulting id, you can convert it to an integer. Then you can use the `userid` integer. 
Do remember to check whether you actually have a result from the SQL query, in case you try to find the userID of an email that does not exist.